# Android Studio - can't select fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have some fragments in my project but when I go to a layout editor and I go to Custom/fragment Android Studio does not list them. Even if I create a fragment via New/Fragment it's still not there:

[image]

My TestFragment for example looks like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    //...
}
```

This is my build config:

[image]

Mabye something with the support library?

Comment: did you try typing the full qualified path to your Fragment manually ?

Comment: Yeah, interestingly the Android Studio content assist even gives me my two fragments but after I insert one of them he complains that he cannot find the symbol. I did a manual gradle synch as well just in case.